# Удаление элемента id без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Всем привет!

Подскажите, как сделать удаление отдельного элемента id с базы, не перезагружая страницу. Я так понимаю, это нужно делать на ajax, пробовал - ничего не получается.

Вот обработчик form.php:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT `id` FROM user_notification WHERE id = '.$id))) {


        }
    } else {
        print "no id";
    }
```

Вот файл отображения оповещений main.php:

```
print " 


}
} else {

}
```

Вот такой пробовал ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').submit(function(){
   var data = {
    id: $('#id').val()
}
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "form.php",  
                    data: data,
                    success: function(html){   
            $("#Result").html(html).css('visibility','visible');                                     
                 }           
                });                 
                return false;  
            });  
    });
```

Comment: @slavapolyakov, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @slavapolyakov, если Вам нужна помощь с кодом AJAX, то его тоже прикрепите, а так если честно, ничего не понятно.

Comment: Так я и прошу помощи составить правильный код ajax

Comment: @slavapolyakov составьте неправильный, а с ошибками вам помогут, иначе это назывется не помощь а работа за вас.

Comment: элемент с id="id" только один на странице?

Comment: Нет, id для каждой записи разный. Вот я и хочу сделать удаление на ajax.

Comment: есть возможность посмотреть на результат всего этого обсуждения? Дайте ссылку на посмотреть

Comment: @slavapolyakov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

1 Замечание насчет замены $_GET на $_POST в скрипте обработчике - верное. Либо в php используйте $_POST, либо в js используйте type:"GET".

2 Избежать путаницы и упростить код поможет использование методов $.get() или $.post()

3 В вашем случае код выглядить должен примерно так: (все это в main.php)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.del_me').click(function(e) {
    var id = e.target.dataset.id;
    // используем POST
    $.post("form.php", { "id": id}, function(resp){
      $("#Result").html(resp).css('visibility','visible');
      $('#'+id).remove(); //удаляем нужный элемент
    });
    // используем GET
    $.get("form.php?id="+$('#id').val(), function(resp){
       $("#Result").html(resp).css('visibility','visible');
       $('#'+id).remove(); //удаляем нужный элемент
    });
  });
});

$sql    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_notification` WHERE uid = '".$user_id."' OR login = '".$login."' ORDER BY id DESC");
if ( mysql_num_rows($sql) ) {
 while($a = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   echo "<div id='".$a['id']."'>".date("d.m.Y H:i", $a['date']).":".$a['text']."<a data-id='".$a['id']."' href='#' class='del_me'>удалить </a></div>";
  }
  echo "<div id='Result'></div>";
 } else {
print "Оповещений нет";
}
```

Comment: Вопрос: в ссылке <a href="form.php?id=".$a['id']."">удалить </a>  что нужно указать?

Comment: надо удалять оповещения со страницы main.php?

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: Все работает, но из базы запись не удаляется. Перезагружаю страницу и запись появляется. Да и после нажатия запись пропадает но в result выходит no id

Comment: @boris_U, Вы зачем учите ТС порочным практикам?! 

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_notification` WHERE uid = '".$user_id."' OR login = '".$login."' ORDER BY id DESC");


Необходимо привести правильный пример и объяснить, почему так делать не надо.

Comment:     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_notification` WHERE uid = '".$user_id."' OR login = '".$login."' ORDER BY id DESC");

@slavapolyakov, поздравляю, у Вас большая дыра!

 * Не используйте процедурный доступ к СУБД. Читаем, что [написано в красной рамке](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)
 * [Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)
 * Почитайте [мой ранее данный ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/393450#393456)

Comment: @romeo: это кусок исходного кода из вопроса - в его сторону я даже и не смотрел.

Comment: @slavapolyakov: таки вы что все-таки используете? get или post? 

Еще раз - просмотрите этот момент и прочтите все комментарии, в которых вам советуют привести все к одному типу запросов.

Если и это не поможет - займитесь отладкой ваших sql-запросов. И да - то, как они у вас написаны - это очень плохо.

Comment: GET запрос везде прописал.

Comment: > в его сторону я даже и не смотрел.

@boris_U, а зря. ТС получит ответ и уйдёт с полной уверенностью, что всё норм. Очередной ["маляр"](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/239339/) в полку php-разработчиков. Стыдно же.

Comment: Я использую CMS adminstation сайт adminstation.ru, я и создаю дополнения опираясь на их запросы. Я проверял на наличие инъекции и все нормально. Вот еще какие там запросы

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deposits WHERE user_id = ".$user_id." ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

Вы мне подскажите, почему не работает удаление на ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к ответу [[@boris_U](/users/30380/boris_u)](/users/30380/boris_u): лучше для удаления элемента из DOM использовать detach():

```
$('#'+id).detach(); //удаляем нужный элемент
```

Comment: @densmith: хмхмхм. detach удаляет, но при этом хранит все связанные с удаленными элементами данные - в надежде на их скорое возвращение. Имеет смысл, если мы делаем проект для девочек - удалить/не удалить/любит/не любит.
А remove - брутальный мужской удалятор - раз и нет :)

Comment: @boris_U, согласен полностью, но в случае с неудачей запроса к базе мы теряем элемент навсегда (до перезагрузки страницы), что может ввести в заблуждение. Особенно когда разработчик еще не очень в теме.

Comment: @densmith: ну да. в этом случае не сжигать все мосты

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался и все работает. Огромное всем спасибо!